# Cannot get the branch information from the scm repository

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I am getting following error in building the maven project. Any idea in  solving this?

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (default) on project pwc-em: Cannot get the branch information from the scm repository :

[ERROR] Exception while executing SCM command. Error while executing command. Error while executing process. Cannot run program "git" (in directory "C:\Users\vmasama\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.2.RELEASE\pwc-em"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
[ERROR] ->
```

Comment: It seems that `git.exe` is searched in a wrong path. Is `git` installed and available in the _PATH_ ?

Comment: it is installed, I'm not sure whether it is available in path or not. How do i check this ?

Comment: Just open a DOS shell (cmd.exe), and type "git", you will see .

Answer (score 7):

I solved the same issue by updating my git version. But downgrading the version of the maven plugin to 1.13 will also solve this issue.

- buildnumber-maven-plugin v1.4 works with git v2.9.2 but **not** with v1.9.*
- buildnumber-maven-plugin v1.3 works with git v1.9.*

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this exception on my windows IDE because git was not configured in PATH variable. After adding git bin in PATH variable and restart the IDE it got fixed.